# C# How to change the ip public?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to change my ip address that is public?
My idea is to surf anonymously

I have seen that some programs can change the public address and I do not know how they will do it

Comment: Thanks for do my day with small reputation, thanks! more thanks for do welcome

Comment: stupid peoples love voting down, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So called proxy programs send your data traffic over a server in a different location so the website or service that you visit gets to see only the ip adress of the proxy server that you are using.

So your data takes the following path:
You -> Proxy Server -> Website -> Proxy Server -> You

Answer (score -1):

Adding on top of what [Jan1902](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4629394/jan1902) said, if you really want to have some privacy, you can also get a VPN service. People usually use VPN for privacy and to access blocked content based on a region.